# jQuery submit into an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, submit

i submit my form into an iframe via jquery. i got the result from the php file in JSON code. How can i use this string in my javascript?

**form**

```
<form target="iframe" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

**response fromupload.php printed into the iframe**

```
{"datafile":{"name":"","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":4,"size":0}}
```

whats the best way to register a callback if the response from the php arrived, and then access to the datafiles 's error property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to attach a load handler to the iframe. `$('#iframe').on('load', handler)` inside the handler you can  get the iframe body and extract the json and parse it for use. You can do something like this in the handler

```
var $body = $(this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow);
if (!$body.is('body')){
    $body = $body.find('body');
}
var data = $.parseJSON($body.html());
```

Note Same Origin Policy applies so this will not work if the post is made to another origin.